# Postfix/Spamassassin can't determine rDNS too often

Tags: postfix, debian-wheezy, reverse-dns, spamassassin

I am running a Debian 7.9 server with Postfix 2.9.6 and Spamassassin 3.3.2.

One of the standard checks Spamassassin does, is to check for a rDNS record. I am assuming that it gets that info from the `Received: from ...` header in the message passed on from Postfix.

Now quite often Postfix fails to resolve a hostname for an IP address which unnecessarily gives a worse score than it deserves, since almost all of the times, a hostname actually exists. If I check these messages manually, I can see that the mentioned header often says `Received: from example.com (unknown [1.2.3.4]) by ...` while at the same time if I try to resolve the IP address myself (in the server's shell) it works without a problem.

What is the issue here? Is there a maybe a too aggressive timeout that doesn't give it enough time? If so, is there a way to adjust this timeout? My server is not getting thousands of messages per minute, so waiting a few more seconds wouldn't hurt. Would switching to DNS over TCP help this issue? If so, how can I tell Postfix to use TCP for DNS queries?

Comment: This should help you http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Reverse-DNS-unknown-td61521.html

Comment: If I understood the linked conversation correctly, the problem that Postfix reports `unknown` is, that the rDNS-hostname doesn't match the EHLO hostname? If so, then unfortunately this is not what is happening with my server. The following lines are from messages which went wrong, even though rDNS resolves to exactly the EHLO hostname und even going back forward to the IP of that host, returns exactly the same IP that connected:
`Received: from nm37-vm5.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com (unknown [98.138.229.133])` and `Received: from nm43-vm1.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com (unknown [67.195.87.216])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was running my Postfix installation with the chroot-setting set to the default "yes". After I set this to "no" (since I am not running it in a chroot), it seems to resolve the issue.

I still don't understand why it seemed to have no problems before but now it works.

The setting in question is in `/etc/postfix/master.cf:` ([Source](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#no_chroot))

```
# =============================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# =============================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd

# This had to be set to "n":    ^
```